# What's the most conventional folder for outputting resources if you need them strictly within build target?

Tags: java, maven, architecture, build, continuous-integration

We all know "inputable" resources are by convention in src/main/resources and src/test/resources, but what about the runtime outputted ones? Is it better to use `target/` or `target/{classes,test-classes}`or simply give up and try to use external path even if it complicates things for security reasons? I've been brainstorming a bit regarding that decission as shown following, but need the help of more experienced users that can shed more light.

**PROS of target/{classes, test-classes}**

- If maven engineers architected the convention by moving resources to target/classes instead of target/resources I assume they had a good reason in mind for preferring it
- It organizes input and output resources on the same base folder
- It makes test and main outputs independent, so no conflict can appear if names are equal
- IT makes much conventional and secure to define the relative route of the resource ( by ClassLoadeR().getResource() or etProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation() [no file globs]
- It makes much easy to centralize output behavior, in case our idea is having a function for UPSERTing resources, we need to use resolution for sufolder as they are not in the same path (so prepend /classes/ to the relative route but / for an original resource)
- I think due to the previous ones, there can be a bit of confusion when using parent poms, because there is a target for both parent and module, but only one classloader URL -> /target/classes
- It works flawlessly if using the classes directory as the base classpath of the app, when executing directly from console.

**PROS of target/**

- When packaging the app as a library, you don't need to deal with an output folder inside the jar.
- I have been told that maven doesn't like too much anything strictly outside of target/, but have no further info
- A central folder can be used when executing tests in case production code generates files and tests works with  them also
- Perhaps a single target at parnet pom's level makes files easier to share among different modules

So how do you usually handle these sort if things?
I am sure some of you have a more authoritative question

Answer (score 1):

So typically if you are allowing resources to be pulled in from outside of your Jar you need to either hard-code that relative path or read it from fixed config file.  You would then document this when you release your application.

For example, Eclipse has a folder specially for plugins.  You can drop new plugins here and know that Eclipse will pick them up and know what to do with them.

In my applications, I usually define a conf directory that sits at the same level as the executable Jar.  I'll put any log4j and other such post-compile config files there.

You mention security issues, which is a good thing to think about.  When you are pulling in data, always try to do some sort of sanity checking (make sure a directory exists, a zip file isn't corrupt, etc).  Since you can't control what comes in, make sure you do as many checks as you can on the program side.

Comment: Thanks!! What if you run/test/compile everything before packaging? Is your approach enough flexible to deal with that? What if you want some predefined resources in main/resources. How do you access the folder? I'd like to avoid specifying a hardcoded path as argument, just to know the convention (like src/main/resources for input),

Comment: The src/main/resources directory is used for resources that are to be bundled inside your applications (jar, war, etc).  These should be things like SQL commands, images, and other resources that aren't dynamic.  You really don't want your users to have to extract your jar in order to add resources.  You would access resources in the src/main/resources directory by using the ClassLoader

(YourClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(name))

I know in Eclipse I can create folders in my project that aren't bundled inside my compiled program and can be accessed using relative paths.

Comment: When you create a application, you can define a new convention that you expect your users to follow.  If that includes knowing where to place input files, that should be documented and conveyed to your users.

Comment: And in case you want it inside target, what is preferrably root target or target/classes?